# bonferroni and scheffé' simultaneous confidence interval graph in minitab

Tags: regression, time-series, multiple-regression, confidence-interval, minitab

I need to calculate bonferroni and scheffé' simultaneous confidence interval by hand as a homework.

However, I also want to add minitab outputs and graphs to my homework task.

How can I plot these two simultaneous CI graphs and analysis outputs in minitab? Especially plotting simultaneous CI graphs is important. Please explain how to use minitab or show me reference book or any else? Thank you.

Especially I want to plot confidence interval graph showing lower&upper bands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can not graph both the CI graphs simultaneously because there is no option for that (in regression analysis) using Minitab.